# c++ undefined refernce to class constructer

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
//Header FILE:
#ifndef BMI_H_INCLUDED
#define BMI_H_INCLUDED

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class BMI{
public:
//default constructer
BMI();
//overloaded
BMI(string,int,double);
private:
string newName;
int newHeight;
double newWeight;
};


#endif // BMI_H_INCLUDED
//Implementation file:
#include "BMI.h"
BMI ::BMI(){
newHeight=0;
newWeight=0.0;

}
BMI::BMI(string name,intheight,double weight){
newName=name;
newHeight=height;
newWeight=weight;
}
//Main file:
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include "BMI.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string name;
int height;
double weight;
cout<<"Name:\n";
getline(cin,name);
cout<<"Height(Inches):\n";
cin>>height;
cout<<"Weight(Pounds):";
cin>>weight;
BMI person_1("John",89,90.0);
//I get the error on the above line error is             //undefinedreferenceto`BMI::BMI(std::string, int, double)'



}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this keeps happening to me?

I use Codeblocks and if so how can I fix this and prevent it from happening again.

This happens every time I separate classes into headers and cpp files. This is just one of the many times my program fails to compile due to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: If this is the only error/warning you get, maybe you should consider switching to a different compiler ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `BMI::BMI(string name,intheight,double weight){` theres no space between int and height.

This causes `BMI person_1("John",89,90.0);` to refer to a constructor that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Twoshock Awesome! dont forget to mark my answer as correct so that others know if they share your problem!